# Recuperar valores de checkbox com ValidationEngine

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando achar a melhor maneira de enviar meus campos via submit para o PHP validar. Tenho um formulário com 4 checkboxes onde ao menos um tem que ser válido.

Estou usando o Validation Engine, no PHP eu trabalho essencialmente com o `Name` do campo e com o `Value`.

Estou usando um exemplo igual a esse:

```
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[2]]" type="checkbox" name="group1" id="maxcheck1" value="5"/>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[2]]" type="checkbox" name="group1" id="maxcheck2" value="3"/>
<input class="validate[minCheckbox[2]]" type="checkbox" name="group1" id="maxcheck3" value="9"/>
```

Só que o `Submit` do PHP pega o name de cada campo, aí nesse caso se o ultimo check estiver selecionado, ele monta como se o "valor" `group1` estivesse `1`...

O Submit do Formulario e basicão, apenas um `input type="submit"`.....

Li a documentação e estou achando dificuldade nesse caso, alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Acho que falta na pergunta: mostrar o submit do PHP, colocar essa tag e dar um título descritivo

Comment: Editei @Brasofilo, e agora? rs

Comment: Vc diz que o problema é no Validation Engine, que é um [plugin jQuery](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/), fala de PHP, mas não mostra nem PHP nem jQuery... Qual a dificuldade?

Comment: @brasofilo . . . o Validation Engine trabalha como se fosse uma class.... ele trabalha com o name do `input` e com o `validate[minCheckbox[2]]` do atributo `class`

Comment: @brasofilo Já o PHP eu já disse... ele recupera o grupo de `checkBox` como se o `$_POST['group1']` fosse 1, ele não recupera o `ID` de cada um, e sim o grupo todo..... acho que foi falta de atenção sua, não pergunta mal formulada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, depois de uma árdua pesquisa, e uma trabalheira enorme, consegui resolver o problema, e deixo aqui a solução pra caso alguém precise utilizar o `validationEngine` com `checkBox`....

Pra utilizar o `validationEngine` em `checkBox` é necessário criar os `inputs` como um `array` em `HTML` desse modo:

```
<input class="validate[required]" type="checkbox" name="group1[]" id="maxcheck1" value="a" onclick="checar(this.id)"/>
<input class="validate[required]" type="checkbox" name="group1[]" id="maxcheck2" value="b" onclick="checar(this.id)"/>
<input class="validate[required]" type="checkbox" name="group1[]" id="maxcheck3" value="c" onclick="checar(this.id)"/>
```

O array é definido no `name="group1[]"` [Não sabia disso, que dá pra criar vetores em HTML desse modo, a titulo de conhecimento]
No lado do PHP eu utilizo:

```
$_POST["maxcheck1"] = 0;
$_POST["maxcheck2"] = 0;
$_POST["maxcheck3"] = 0;

$checkBox = $_POST['group1'];
if ($checkBox) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $checkBox as $value ) {
        switch ($value) {
            case "maxcheck1" :
                $_POST["maxcheck1"] = 1;
                break;
            case "maxcheck2" :
                $_POST["maxcheck2"] = 1;
                break;
            case "maxcheck3" :
                $_POST["maxcheck3"] = 1;
                break;
            default :break;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

E por fim, pra recuperar esses valores no meu formulário eu utilizo as funções:

```
function checkar() {    
    var idsObj = new Array("maxcheck1", "maxcheck2", "maxcheck3");    
    for (var i = 0; i < (idsObj.length); i++) {
        if (document.getElementById(idsObj[i]).value == 1) {
            //$(idsObj[i]).prop("checked", true);
            document.getElementById(idsObj[i]).value = idsObj[i];
            document.getElementById(idsObj[i]).checked = true;
        } else {
            //$(idsObj[i]).prop("checked", false);
            document.getElementById(idsObj[i]).value = 0;
            document.getElementById(idsObj[i]).checked = false;
        }
    }
}

function checar(idObj) {
    val = idObj;
    idObj = "#" + idObj;
    if ($(idObj).is(':checked')) {
        $(idObj).val(val);
    } else {
        $(idObj).val(0);
    }
}
```